# Excel-VBA : Skip subroutine if cell is empty

Tags: vba, excel

Ok, so I have 10 columns, labelled "A"-"J".

Each Row will have some combination of these columns filled in with string values.

I need to run some conditional statements and I'm wondering if there is a more efficient method of doing them without simply looping through them all.

What I have now:

```
If isempty("A1) then
Else
    if isempty("B1") then
    else
        Sheet2!"B1" = "A1  and B1"
    end if
    if isempty("C1") then
    else
        Sheet2!"A1" = "A1 and C1"
    end if
    [...etc]
end if

If isempty("B1) then
Else
    if isempty("C1") then
    else
        Sheet2!"B1" = "B1 and C1"
    end if
    if isempty("D1") then
    else
        Sheet2!"C1" = "C1 and D1"
    end if
    [...etc]
end if
```

It's long, cumbersome, and not very pretty.  Moreover, it takes a long time because we have a few hundred records (rows) to go through.  Is there a faster way to look at X Row, say A,B,C,E,&J have things, and do stuff based on that.

```
If A,C,&J are filled Do this.. 
If B is empty do this...
If C Or D is full, do this other thing.
```

Comment: You are looking for logical operators ("and" and "or" operators). e.g. if isempty("c1") and isempty(b1) then... see: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/logical-operators.html

Comment: I may just knock myself out with how hard of a face-palm this is.  It's so obvious, just staring me in the face.  >.<

    Isempty(A) = A;
    Isempty(B) = B;

    IF A and B DO...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure of the order in which cells should be checked but perhaps this will get you started.

```
Dim rw As Long, lr As Long
With Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
    lr = .Rows.Count
    For rw = 1 To lr
        If Application.CountA(Range("A" & rw & ",C" & rw & ",J" & rw)) = 3 Then
            'If A,C,&J are filled Do this..
        ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("B" & rw)) Then
            'If B is empty do this...
        ElseIf CBool(Application.CountA(Range("C" & rw & ",D" & rw))) Then
            'If C Or D is full, do this other thing.
        End If
    Next rw
End With
```